# Form not submitting even with form action parameter explicitly set

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't usually have a lot of trouble with django form submission, but i can't seem to figure out what am not doing right for my code to work. Done some reading here at stackoverflow but no luck.

In my template, i define a form that is rendered within a twitter bootstrap modal,

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <form method="post" action="{%url 'item_order' item.id %}">
   <input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="add to order"/>
 </form>
```

In the form header, i want to explicitly have the form submit to this view,

```
def show_item(request,id):
    a = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = partial_order_item_form()
        final_form = form(request.POST)
        # check validation of posted data
        if final_form.is_valid():
            order.add_to_order(request,a)
            url =urlresolvers.reverse('order_index',kwargs={'id':a.id})
            # redirect
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^item/(?P<id>\d+)/$',show_item, name="item_order")
```

To my suprise, the form will not submit to this view, in fact it will not do anything at all. This beats my understanding, i thought if i have explicitly set the action in the form header, it would work as i intend it to.

What am not doing right? Links are appreciated as well.

**Edit**
Inspecting with firebug as pointed out by @danihp, i have learnt that when the browser renders the page it closes the form before rendering all django template logic i want it to.

```
<form method="post" action="orders/item/2"></form>
<input class="btn btn-large btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="add to order"/>
```

so when i submit nothing happens because the input element is not in the form.

**SOLVED**

Check out my answer.

Comment: install firebug and debug what is happening.

Comment: What do you mean, "it will not do anything at all"? What exactly happens when you press the submit button? And you should probably post your urls.

Comment: Is the url with name 'item_order' really mapping to the show_item method?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, provided the urls @DanielRoseman, by nothing i mean it wont redirect.

Comment: Well, your HTML code that you pased in your edit cannot result from your template code at the beginning. And btw, the browser has absolutely nothing to do with your template logic. The template is rendered by the server and the browser only recieves plain HTML.

Comment: @schacki, i got that.

Answer (score 0):

Looking aroung i found the same [problem and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687258/form-issue-closing-itself-early-in-table). It happens my html markup was poorly written, the mentioned problem and solution helped figure it out.